# Running a MYSQLI command in while loop which is inside a for each loop but only returning 1 value

Tags: php

I am trying to get the while loop to get all the results from the database but it is only returning 1 result even though there are more than one. Only inside the while loop it produces 1 result but the foreach loop runs twice.

I have tried searching for a solution but cant find one.

```php
$classes = "03, 06";

$allclasses = explode(',', $classes);

$studentclasses = "";

foreach ($allclasses as $classes) {

    $getclassname = "SELECT * FROM Classes WHERE Code='$classes'";
    $getclassname = mysqli_query($conn, $getclassname);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getclassname)) {
        $classname = $row['ClassName'];
        echo $classname;
    }

        /*
        echo "  <li>
        <a href='classdetails.php?studentid=$studentid&classcode=$classes'>

    <span class='sidebar-mini-icon'>$classes</span>
    <span class='sidebar-normal'>$classname</span>
        </a> </li>";
        */


}
```

the while loop should return 2 $classname although it only returns one at the moment.

Comment: This data being put into the sql query is data from the server that has been checked before being entered directly into the server.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Does mysqli_escape_string($conn, $string) suffice to not allow SQL injection? I have attempted SQL Injections into the database using some of the fields but havent managed to extract data out by hacking

Comment: Forget about the existence of `mysqli_escape_string`, it is only for legacy code and it is not supposed to be a protection against SQL injection. To protect from SQL injections use prepared statements. Please read the links I provided carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
$allclasses = explode(',', $classes);
```

To

```
$allclasses = explode(', ', $classes);
```

Alternatively you can add following line to the start of your foreach cycle.

```
$classes = trim($classes);
```

The point is that in the second iteration of foreach cycle the value of `$classes` is `' 06'` while the Code in DB is probably `'06'`

Comment: Wow thanks alot. I tried to do this and thought i had. the trim method worked perfectly. Thanks alot.